# Is there an IDE with a GUI designer for Perl?

Tags: perl, ide, ui-design

Can anyone suggest me a easy to use Perl language IDE with GUI designing support for Ubuntu.

Comment: The suggested duplicate is *3 years* old.  Is Perl evolving so slowly that no new tools were built in the last 3 years?

Comment: Why the _close_ votes? The _duplicate_ is not only three years old, but really doesn't answer this particular question. OP is looking for a IDE and not a GUI builder.

Comment: Perl has bindings to multiple GUI toolkits. For GUI designers look at the toolkit you want to use (Wx/GTK/Qt/Whatever). Otherwise, any editor will cut it for Perl. Even Gedit should be fine for a start. (I myself use Kate, and *lots* of open terminals for documentation & testing snippets)

Comment: @DavidW. Closing as a duplicate is not a bad thing. It would be a good idea to update the original (older) question with new information. Then, this and any others closed as duplicates would point to the original with the now updated information instead of knowledge being scattered around. To be sure, this is a constructive question, but it is a duplicate. I do not understand the "not constructive" votes either.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the [EPIC](http://www.epic-ide.org) plugin for Eclipse. I've used that a few times, and if you like Eclipse, it's very nice.

If you never used Eclipse before, you need to download Eclipse, install it, and then install the EPIC plugin.

[Komodo](http://www.activestate.com/komodo-ide) is one of the nicest IDEs for Perl, works with Linux, and is now on sale for only $245!

Gabor Szabo, one of the big Perl mucki-mucks, created [Padre](http://padre.perlide.org). I have never used it, but if Szabo was involved, it's probably pretty good.

I personally use VIM. Yes, it's not an *IDE*, but it does syntax highlighting, and you can reference the Perldoc by pressing `K` over a keyword or module name. VIM isn't as easy to use as an IDE, but I find editing in VIM much faster than most IDEs.

Comment: The OP is not asking just for IDEs but for IDEs with GUI designers.